# DWC OTG Controller - 0x1d Offset

Tags: raspberry-pi2

If the DWC OTG Controller has base address of 0x3f980000 on the Raspberry Pi2 running Raspbian then it appears that merely loading from said address with offset 0x1d, via virtual address of 0x76ff8000 created by mmap, causes it to lock up/freeze and a power cycle is required to restore.

```
    ...
 17         .baseaddr:      .word   0x3f980000    // base address
...
 23         // set up file and virtual map to it............ */
 24         bl open_file
 25         str r0, [sp, #0]    // store file handler on stack
 26         bl map_file
 27         str r0, [sp, #8]    // store virt GPIO mem address on stack
 28
 32         ldr r3, [sp, #8]    // virt base address
 34         ldr r2, [r3, #0x1d] // get contents
```

Once the load at line 34 takes place, the device is still detectable on LAN but wlan0 and eth0 are unresponsive and port scanning returns null.

Does anyone has any idea of what monster is crouched behind door 0x1d that's scaring the bits out of the DWC OTG controller?

Answer (score 1):

Given that 0x1d creates and odd address, I would guess the system takes an address exception at that point (load 32 from odd address). You might try offset ox1c or 0x20 for better results.